# Php and GWT/Java (Apache & Tomcat) on the same server - good idea?

Tags: php, tomcat, java, gwt

I have a Flex RIA solution served by a Php backend up and running.

Because of the growing needs for system admin, 
I would like to implement a GWT/Java solution for this.

It seems to be possible to have Apache and Tomcat serving the java parts
using mod_jk.

Are there and drawbacks in such a setup? Performance? Security?

Regards / Jonas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem at all proxying Tomcat via an existing Apache httpd instance. You might want to look into mod_proxy- it's easier than mod_jk. You might also want to look at this article: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/06/16/deciding-between-modjk-modproxyhttp-and-modproxyajp